# Make a console window goto the front when a hotkey is pressed

Tags: python, console, ctypes

For a project I am doing i need a console window to become the focus window when a hotkey is pressed. In this case it is F2. I have fixed the hotkey segment of the code now i need to have the console window become the focus.

I currently have:

```
import win32gui
import win32con, ctypes.wintypes, ctypes

def bringtofront():
    #win32gui.ShowWindow(self, win32con.SW_MAXIMIZE) something like this?
    print "now at the front!"

ctypes.windll.user32.RegisterHotKey(None, 1, 0, win32con.VK_F2)  
while True:

    try:
        msg = ctypes.wintypes.MSG()
        while ctypes.windll.user32.GetMessageA(ctypes.byref(msg), None, 0, 0) != 0:
            if msg.message == win32con.WM_HOTKEY:
                bringtofront()
            ctypes.windll.user32.TranslateMessage(ctypes.byref(msg))
            ctypes.windll.user32.DispatchMessageA(ctypes.byref(msg))
    finally:
        ctypes.windll.user32.UnregisterHotKey(None, 1)
```

Just to clarify the part of the code i am having trouble with is

```
win32gui.ShowWindow(self, win32con.SW_MAXIMIZE)
```

Comment: Unclear from your question, but `win32gui.SetFocus()` or `win32gui.SetForegroundWindow()` might be what you want.

Comment: Try unhiding,  restoring,  setting to foreground, and setting focus: `hWnd = win32console.GetConsoleWindow();` `win32gui.ShowWindow(hWnd, win32con.SW_SHOW);` `win32gui.ShowWindow(hWnd, win32con.SW_RESTORE);` `win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);  win32gui.SetFocus(hWnd)`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633548%28v=vs.85%29.aspx it would seem you need to use `SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED`, although I haven't tried it...